# Verbatim command arguments: deparse(substitute(foo)) in a wrapper

Tags: r

Here's a little puzzler for those fluent in the nitty-gritty of how the R evaluator handles function calls.  Suppose I wanted to write a function that takes an R statement, same as what I'd write at the command line, and echoes both it, and the evaluated result.  Example:

```
 > p.eval(sum(1:3))
 sum(1:3) --> 6
```

That's easy; here's the definition of `p.eval()`:

```
p.eval <- function(v,prefix="--> ") { 
   cmd <- deparse(substitute(v)); cat(cmd,prefix,v,"\n") 
}
```

But suppose I now want to write a wrapper around p.eval, to be invoked the same way; perhaps as a somewhat demented binary operator with a dummy second argument:

```
%PE% <- function(x,...) p.eval(x)
```

I'd like to invoke it like so: `sum(1:3) %PE% 0` should be equivalent to the old `p.eval(sum(1:3))`.  This doesn't work, of course, because the `deparse(substitute())` of `p.eval()` now gives `x`.

Question to the enlightened: is there a way to make this work as I desire?..  For this particular usage, I'm quite fine with defining `%PE%` by copying/pasting the one-liner definition of `p.eval`, so this question is mostly academic in nature.  Maybe I'll learn something about the nitty-gritty of the R evaluator :)

P.S.: Why might one find the above functions useful?..  Suppose I develop some analysis code and invoke it non-interactively through org-babel (which is most definitely worth playing with if you are an Org-mode and/or an Emacs user).  By default, org-babel slurps up the output as things are evaluated in the interpreter.  Thus, if I want to get anything but raw numbers, I have to explicitly construct strings to be printed through `cat` or `paste`, but who wants to do that when they are flying through the analysis?..  The hack above allows you to simply append %PE%0 after a line that you want printed, and this echoes the command to the org output.

Comment: If you're going this route, I'd advise reading https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation, particularly the "Calling from another function" section

Comment: Excellent resource, Hadley.  Looking forward to completion of the other sections.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
> "%PE%" <- function(x, ...) do.call(p.eval, list(substitute(x)))
> sum(1:3) %PE% 0
sum(1:3) -->  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Also could just have p.eval return "v" and then:

```
 p.eval <- function(v,prefix="--> ") {
        cmd <- deparse(substitute(v)); cat(cmd,prefix,v,"\n") ; return(v)  } 
"%PE%" <- function(x, y=NULL) x 
 sum(1:3) %PE% Inf
 #[1] 6  
sum(1:3) %PE%   # won't accept single argument
  r   # give it anything
 #[1] 6
```